# Too many pages causes Wordpress admin to be unusable

Tags: pages, wp-admin, mysql

We have a Wordpress website that now has around 9k pages in it after an import of many location targeted pages. The frontend runs perfectly fine and there is no performance damage (after I replaced wp_list_pages with a custom MySQL query), but the Page administration section can't even be touched. All other sections of the admin open fine. Even if I navigate to a page on the frontend and use the Edit Page link, it's never able to pull up the Edit Page screen. Changing permalink structure doesn't help, which I know that was an issue with pre 3.0 wordpress. Also tried disabling all plugins, no help there. I'm running on Wordpress 3.3.2.

Halp please! My only alternative I'm thinking would be to split the website up into smaller subsites built on a Wordpress Network, but that would cause at least a month of delay of restructuring the entire website.

Someone mentioned using https://github.com/rackerhacker/MySQLTuner-perl to optimize my.cnf and MySQL. I'll have to see if this is doable on my host, if not then we'll have to move. Anyone else's thoughts would be very appreciated, thanks!

**EDIT**
A wordpress developer mentioned that I could "turn off hierarchical display in edit.php. A
 filter in wp_edit_posts_query() might be able to accommodate this" as a potential workaround. Does any one have experience in dealing with something like that?

Comment: Nothing seems to be working, even tried out 2 different hosts  :(   it looks like I'm going to have to attempt splitting the site into multiple Wordpress Network sites. This seems so silly that Wordpress has such an inefficient query to pull up a page edit screen that literally breaks the admin.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the details you've provided are a bit limited. For example, what sort of hosting are you on and what sort traffic are you dealing with here?

If you have a shared hosting account then you should know that shared hosts provide you with limited cpu and memory resources as it's shared across multiple hosting accounts.

In my experience when wp starts to act up either on the frontend or the admin - it's due to a query returning large results, be it posts, pages, or images - it's definitely resource related, either not enough memory allocated to php or not enough cpu power to complete a process.

Sometimes an unoptimized database could be the cause as well - you could try http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-dbmanager/

Comment: We do run on a shared hosting account right now. If it's strictly a resource issue that a dedicated server would fix, I just wanted to make sure of that before we spent the money and made the jump. Right now there is no traffic as the website is under development. I'll see if that plugin helps any as well, thanks!

Comment: Also, hardware wise, the memory limit is set to 256M in both wordpress' config and in PHP settings.

Comment: While it's common practice now for hosts to provide access to the php.ini file to modify - the memory limit, no matter how high you set it, is capped by the host. Meaning if you set it to 256M the host may cap it at 64M. You'll need to verify that with them. You may as well mention to them the issue and they may be able to tell you definitely if it's a resource issue or not.

Comment: You can also search for a VPS hosting that offers refund, so you can try and withdraw if the issue is not solved.

Comment: Gave the DB manager optimizer a shot too, that didn't help. Dang. Wordpress must be running some seriously funky queries in order to just pull up a single edit page, it seems like it should be extremely simple - not complex enough to time out after adding just a few thousand pages.